# ZigZag Tree Traversal

Tags: tree, zigzag

Given a Binary Tree. Find the Zig-Zag Level Order Traversal of the Binary Tree.
Your Task:
You don't need to read input or print anything. Your task is to complete the function zigZagTraversal() which takes the root node of the Binary Tree as its input and returns a list containing the node values as they appear in the Zig-Zag Level-Order Traversal of the Tree.
For Example: For the below binary tree the zigzag order traversal will be 1 3 2 7 6 5 4. Binary Tree Example[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r72Nl.png)
Input:
3
/   
2     1
Output: 3 1 2

My Code is showing **segmentation fault**

```
   enter code here
vector <int> zigZagTraversal(Node* root)
{
    // Code here
    if(root==0)
    {
        return {0};
    }
    stack<Node *> s1;
    stack<Node *> s2;
    vector<int> m;
    m.push_back(root->data);
    s1.push(root->left);
    s1.push(root->right);
    
    
    while(s1.empty()==false || s2.empty()==false)
    {
        if(s1.empty()==false)
        {
            while(s1.empty()==false)
            {Node *f=s1.top();
                if(s1.top()->right!=0)
                {
                    s2.push(f->right);
                }
                if(s1.top()->left!=0)
                {
                    s2.push(f->left);
                }
                m.push_back(f->data);
                s1.pop();
            }
        }
        else if(s2.empty()==false)
        {
            while(s2.empty()==false)
            {
                if(s2.top()->left!=0)
                {Node *f=s2.top();
                    s1.push(f->left);
                }
                if(s2.top()->right!=0)
                {Node *f=s2.top();
                    s1.push(f->right);
                }
               Node *f=s2.top();
                m.push_back(f->data);
                s2.pop();
            }
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//hope this helps u
void zigZagTraversal(Node *root)
{
    int h=0;
    queue<pair<Node*,int>> q;
    Node *t;
    map<int,vector<int>> m;
    vector<int> v;
    q.push({root,h});
    while(!q.empty()){
        t=q.front().first;
        h=q.front().second;
        q.pop();
        if(t){
            m[h].push_back(t->data);
            q.push({t->left,h+1});
            q.push({t->right,h+1});
        }
    }
    for(auto i=m.begin();i!=m.end();i++){
        v=m[i->first];
        if(!((i->first)%2)){
            reverse(v.begin(),v.end());
        }
        for(auto j=v.begin();j!=v.end();j++) cout<<*j<<" ";
    }
}
```